# VLC lowers volume when window loses focus (playing always on top)

Tags: audio, vlc-media-player

Is there a setting that causes VLC to lower the volume when the playing window loses focus (while playing always-on-top)?

This happens on my laptop and I cannot find a setting to keep the volume consistent whether I'm on focus or viewing a different window.  This does not happen with any other media player.

Thanks.

Comment: You may want to look at `Tools > Preferences > Audio` and try selecting a different `Output module`. Each output modules use a separate API and thus may behave differently. It's also probably worth mentioning that if you use VLC as a "app" in Windows 10 (versus downloading the "regular" version of VLC for Windows), as far as I am aware, Windows may decrease the volume of apps based on its own criteria.

Answer (score 7):

Found the issue - On Lenovo laptops (I have a G50), Dolby Digital Plus has a "Volume Leveler" which is OFF by default ... when it is off (the default), the volume changes when window focus changes (no idea why).  Switching the leveler to ON fixes the problem.

[Dolby Digital](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJUas.png)

Comment: Same problem with the Lenovo P1 Gen 2, except that application is called "Dolby Atmos Speaker System" and I had to click the power button in the top left to make it stop.